# making Javascript variables into global variables

Tags: javascript

I use my `getHTML()` function in a different function which parses through data, and I display the data as an HTML string. When the user is done filling the form, I want to send that information along with the username and examid. The username and examid are also coming from the backend at the position `data[0].username` and `data[1].examid` How can I make these two attributes into global variables, so that I can use them in my send function?

```
  function getHTML(data){
     var htmlString = "";
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            htmlString += "<p>"
                          + data[i].questionid + "." + "\n"
                          + "Question: " + data[i].question
                          + "\n" + "<input type='text' value1='" 
                          +data[i].username+ " value2='" +data[i].examid+ "'>";                 
           htmlString += '</p>';
        }
        response.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
    }   

   function send(){ 
           var inputText = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");

            var data = []; 
            for(var index = 0; index < inputText.length; index++){

                input = inputText[index].value;
                data.push({'text' : input});
            }  
            data.push({'username' : username, 'examid' : examid});
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable out of any function so they would be global

```
var username;
var examid;

function(){...}
function(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.username = data[i].username;` and `window.examid = data[i].examid`.

Though you may be trying to store more than one in which case you want an array.

You are looking to use the `window` element if you want it in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code might help you

```js
(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Node").value;
    document.getElementById("Node").onchange = function() {
      myNode()
    };
    document.getElementById("mySelect1").onchange = function() {
      myNotes()
    };
    document.getElementById("mySelect2").onclick = function() {
      summary()
    };

    function myNode() {
      x = document.getElementById("Node").value;
    }

    function summary() {
      var a = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
      document.getElementById("5").value = a + " - " + b + " - " + x;
    }

    function myNotes() {

      var a = document.getElementById("mySelect1").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
      document.getElementById("4").value = a + " + " + b + " + " + x;
    }


  }





)();
```

```html
Notes : <input type="text" id="4" /><br> Summary : <input type="text" id="5" /><br>
<select id="Node">
      <option value="w">w
      <option value="x">x
      <option value="y">y
      <option value="z">z
    </select>
<select id="mySelect2">
      <option value="a">a
      <option value="b">b
      <option value="c">c
      <option value="d">d
    </select>
<select id="mySelect1">
      <option value="1">1
      <option value="2">2
      <option value="3">3
      <option value="4">4
    </select>
```